# How can I implement a button in my app so every time a user presses it, the whole app default colour changes

Tags: ios, button, colors, themes, default

As the title says,
 I would like to implement a button so when a user presses it once, the general default colour changes. Say the user presses the button once and the app theme becomes green and when pressed again, the theme changes to red and pressed again it goes back to the initial theme colour. 
Does anyone have a quick example? On google, when I search the above, all I get is how the change the colour of a button. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes simply hook up an action and whenever the UIButton is pressed call:

```
CGFloat red =  (CGFloat)arc4random() / (CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
CGFloat blue = (CGFloat)arc4random() / (CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
CGFloat green = (CGFloat)arc4random() / (CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
self.view.backgroundColor = color;
```

These lines of code basically generate random RGB numbers and turnes the views color to that color.

To change the other view controllers view:

```
yourViewController.view.backroundColor = color;
```

Comment: I'll give it a try right now. Thanks @Abdullah Shafique

Comment: @Dashony You welcome! Hope my answer helps :)

Comment: I like the random colours, but what will I have to add to it so it changes the colours globally not just in the view where the button is placed? @Abdullah Shafique

Comment: Xcode 5 has this Global tint. Only if I can use your code to generate this random colours as values for the Global Tint. Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: @Dashony I do no how to do the global tint...Sorry I guess you must ask a separate question.

Comment: I'll play around with this one. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You could create a singleton class (e.g. `AppearanceManager`) where you would keep your `currentTheme`. From your button action you can set this theme to whatever you want. You can also override the setter of this variable, and post a `notification` indicating that the theme changed.

Comment: Thanks @Levi your concept sounds good but a little too complicated for me. Appreciate your input.